# Mongoose group aggregation don't return the rest of fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hello i have the following code working now:

```
 app.get('/api/checkAv/:checkIn/:checkOut', function(req, res) {
    var checkIn = req.params.checkIn,
        checkOut = req.params.checkOut,
        roomType = req.params.roomType,
        startDate = moment(checkIn),
        endDate = moment(checkOut),
        nights = endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');
            model.Av.aggregate([
                {$match: {dateOfDay: {$gte: new Date(checkIn), $lt:new Date(checkOut)} }},
                {$group: {
                    _id: '$roomId',
                    total: {$sum: '$price'},
                    count: {$sum: 1},
                    avg: {$avg: '$price'}
                }},
                { $match: { count: { $gte: nights } } }
              ], function (err, result) {
             if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(result);

        });
});
```

it return me something like:

```
[
{
"_id": "545b4848344044fa3ec9ac74",
"total": 180,
"count": 2,
"avg": 90
}
]
```

but i want to return me also some other field from the collection that i don't need/have them in the group clause eg : available , price ...

Reading the Mongoose docs i understand i need to use $project for this issue so i added something like:

```
{$project: {price: "$price"}}
```

and now i get only empty results ... I tried adding in the $group cause something like :

price: '$price' no success i get : "exception: the group aggregate field 'price' must be defined as an expression inside an object", i goggled the errors without success how should i accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add them to the `$group`, but you need to use one of the [accumulator operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#accumulators) that determine how you want the multiple values per `_id` (`roomId`) to be reduced to a single value.

If you think about it, just adding `price: "$price"` makes no sense as which price value would you expect it to use?

So it would need to be something like:

```
price: {$first: '$price'} // To use the first price for this roomId (be sure to sort)
```

or

```
price: {$push: '$price'} // To put all of the prices for this roomId into an array
```

or

```
price: [$max: '$price'} // To use the maximum of all the prices for this roomId
```

etc...hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: thank you price: {$first: '$price'} was what i was looking for